# How to know when an aplication is visible "now" in the screen Android

Tags: android, kotlin, service, background, android-workmanager

I want to achieve the following behavior:

The application should detect if other application is open and show a message on a Log.
For example: If open the Facebook application I should see on the Logcat:

```
 Log.d(TAG, "Facebook was open").
```

I'm currently using a Service, that is looking each second which application is open. I'm not using `WorkManager` because I need to always check the application that is visible for the user. (Work Manager has a margin of **15 minutes** between each request on the background).

Unfortunately, my code always returns the package name of my application and not of the application shown "`now`" on the screen.
How is possible to not only see my application but the currently open application?

This is the code I'm using to show the current application on the screen (fails because always shows my own application).

```
fun isAppRunning (context: Context, packageName: String): Boolean {
    val activityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    val procInfos: List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> = activityManager.runningAppProcesses
    if (procInfos != null) {
        for (processInfo in procInfos) {
            Log.d("TAG", "the application now in screen is "+
                    processInfo.processName)
            if (processInfo.processName == packageName) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

This is how I'm calling this function on the Service:

```
isAppRunning(applicationContext, "com.facebook.katana")
```

Comment: The technique that you are using has not worked in years on modern versions of Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see, thanks, and how is the modern way to achieve it?

Comment: There isn't one, AFAIK. There are significant privacy and security issues involved in apps having real-time access to what the user is doing with respect to other apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the closest you can get but you will still require a special permission (not runtime). You will have to store values and compared to the last used time:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager